# Typing words in WebStorm automatically transforms into them tags

Tags: html, autocomplete, attributes, webstorm

I've been working on an HTML project without any issues, but suddenly, WebStorm has started automatically transforming regular words into tags whenever I hit the Enter key, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

I've created [a short demonstration video to showcase the problem in action.](https://gyazo.com/76293b30551117768d6c52cb7728cef8) As you can see, every time I type a word and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it's being turned into a tag.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before? If so, could you please share how you managed to resolve it? Any help would be very appreciated, thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: **1)** Looks like Emmet in action. What do you have as the Expand key at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Emmet`? By default it should be `Tab`. **2)** What kind of file is that? Plain `.html` or some another? **3)** Does it happen in all files or in some files only? **4)** Does the issue persists in a brand new empty project with just 1 file only?

Comment: **5)** Will it get any better if you disable ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins and restart the IDE? It could be one of the plugins that injects another context (so it's not plain HTML anymore but some JSX or alike). List your custom plugins here. **6)** Locate such a file in the Project View panel, select it and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` on it. Show a screenshot of the popup.